# only some of my css style comes out onto my html file

Tags: html, css

I can get everything else to work but the table down. 
The body font worked, the headers worked and the 
blockquote worked but i cant get the table to show up. 
please help me im new at this.

```
body {
    font-family: verdana, geneva, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: small;
}
h1, h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #cc6600;
    border-bottom: thin dotted #888888;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 170%;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 130%;
}         
blockquote {
    font-style: italic;
}
table {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border: thin solid black;
    caption-side: bottom;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
    border: thin dotted gray;
    padding: 5px;
}
caption {
    font-style: italic;
    padding-top: 8px;
}
```

here is my html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//w3c//dtd xhtml 1.0 strict//en"
"http://www.w3.org/tr/xhtml1/dtd/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http:http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml: lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myjournal.css">

<title>My Trip Around the USA on a Segway eating shit</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Segway'n USA</h1>
 <p>Documenting my trip around the US on my very own Segway!</p>
 <h2>August 20, 2005</h2>
 <p><img src="images/segway2.jpg" alt="" /></p>
 <p>Well I made it 1200 miles already, and I passed through some 
 interesting places on the way:</p>
 <table summary="This table holds data about the cities I 
 visited on my    travels. I've included the date I was in 
 each city, the temperature when I was there, and altitude and 
 population of     each city. I've also included a rating of 
 the diners   where 
 I had lunch, on a scale from 1 to 5.">
 <caption>The cities I visited on my Segway'n USA travels</caption>
 <tbody>
  <tr><th>City</th><th>Date</th><th>Temperature</th>
  <th>Altitude</th><th>Population</th><th>Diner Rating</th></tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Walla Walla, WA</td>
 <td>June 15th</td>
<td>75</td>
<td>1,204 ft</td>
<td>29,686</td>
 <td>4/5</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td>Magic City, ID</td>
<td>June 25th</td>
 <td>74</td>
<td>5.312 ft</td>
<td>50</td>
<td>3/5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Bountiful, UT</td>
<td>July 10th</td>
<td>91</td>
<td>4,226 ft</td>
<td>41,173</td>
<td>4/5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Chance, CO</td>
<td>July 23rd</td>
<td>102</td>
<td>4,780 ft</td>
<td>265</td>
<td>3/5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Truth or Consequences, NM</td>
<td>August, 9th</td>
<td>93</td>
<td>4,242 ft</td>
<td>7,289</td>
<td>5/5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Why, AZ</td>
<td>August, 18th</td>
<td>104</td>
<td>860 ft</td>
<td>480</td>
<td>3/5</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<h2>July 14, 2005</h2>
<p>I saw some Burma Shave style signs on the side of the road today:</p>
<blockquote>
passing cars,<br>
when you can't see,  <br>
May get you, <br> 
A glimpse, <br> 
of eternity. <br>
</blockquote>
<p>I definitely won't be passing any cars.</p>
<h2>June 2, 2005</h2>
<p><img src="images/segway1.jpg" alt="" /></p>
<p>My first day of the trip! I can't believe I finally got 
 everything packed    and ready to go. Because I'm on a Segway, 
  I wasn't able to bring a whole lot with me:</p>
<ul>
    <li>cell phone</li>
    <li>ipod</li>
    <li>digital camera</li>
    <li>a protein bar</li>
</ul>
<p>Just the essentials. As Lao Tzu would have said, 
<q>A journey of a thousand miles begins with one Segway.</q></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please post your html code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close your h1 definition.

```
h1 {
    font-size: 170%;
} /* here! */
```

Comment: And use some syntax highlighting text processor or IDE!

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian: yes I did and tested the code after and before, but maybe you can help me understanding what im missing?

Comment: yeah its right on my file it copied wrong in this forum i fixed that but still cant figure out why my table doesnt show up

Comment: he said that he is not able to show up the table and not about the header

Comment: Not closing the header breaks the css and doesnt process the table. You can try the code ;)

Comment: @BenSmith what do you mean with your table doesnt show up? This is your code: http://jsfiddle.net/Tq8Nr/

Comment: in the web page it doesn't show a table when i put it in my css file

Comment: +1 and sorry without html i was not able to find the error..!!  :)

Comment: is it because im using accountsupport.com from bizland i should use jsfiddle.net. this is the page it shows me http://bsmithpci.accountsupport.com/journal/journal.html

Comment: Refresh cache? ;) (shift+reload in chrome) your website looks ok to me

Comment: thanks @laffuste that helped It was driving me crazy all day like i said im really new at this only a week into learning. Thanks everyone